# I'm using Force.com sites to integrate Wordpress and Salesforce

Tags: integration, force.com-sites, wordpress, seo

My website wordpress website www.liquidlearning.com was integrated with salesforce. The events page www.liquidlearing.com/events is a force.com page. How do I gain SEO benefits from the content on this page?